# Return list of Nodes a Tree in Java-Parent can have multiple child Nodes

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to write java code to return list of Nodes in a tree.
The tree looks like [image: this]

Node class is

```
class Node{
 String label;
 List<Node> children;
}
```

I am trying this way. But not able to understand how to write a loop to traverse.

```
    public List<Node> returnAllNodes(Node node){
    List<Node> listOfNodes = 
        new ArrayList<Node>();
    boolean iterationCompleted = false;
    if(node==null){
        return null;
    }
    while(!iterationCompleted){
    if(node.getChildren()==null){
        listOfNodes.add(node);
                    break;    
    }
            else{
               //
            }
    }
    return null;
    //return traverseAndReturnAllNodes(node.getChildren().get(0));
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You will need to recurse (you could, say, have a stack of `Node`s for where you are, but that's not so elegant). Each iteration of the while look (posh for loop would be better) should `add` the child node and `addAll` the list from the recursive call to get the child node's descendents. (There are some changes you can make to get the lists back in different orders.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're certain that the structure is a tree (a node cannot have more than one parent), this will list the nodes in depth-first order:

```
public static List<Node> returnAllNodes(Node node){
    List<Node> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    addAllNodes(node, listOfNodes);
    return listOfNodes;
}

private static void addAllNodes(Node node, List<Node> listOfNodes) {
    if (node != null) {
        listOfNodes.add(node);
        List<Node> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            for (Node child: children) {
                addAllNodes(child, listOfNodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If nodes can have several parents, change the first line of addAllNodes to:

```
    if (node != null && !listOfNodes.contains(node)) {
```

The breadth-first algorithm goes like this:

```
public static List<Node> returnAllNodes(Node node){
    List<Node> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    if (node != null) {
        listOfNodes.add(node);
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfNodes.size(); ++i) {
            Node n = listOfNodes.get(i);
            List<Node> children = n.getChildren();
            if (children != null) {
                for (Node child: children) {
                    if (!listOfNodes.contains(child)) {
                        listOfNodes.add(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return listOfNodes;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Answer (score 0):

As a enhancement to Maurice Perry's answer for DFS based approach. In case child nodes are alone needed (as parent node is already known), then instead of adding the node always to listOfNodes, child node can alone be added as

```
public static List<Node> returnAllNodes(Node node){
    List<Node> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    addAllNodes(node, listOfNodes);
    return listOfNodes;
}

private static void addAllNodes(Node node, List<Node> listOfNodes) {
    if (node != null) {
        List<Node> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            for (Node child: children) {
                listOfNodes.add(child);
                addAllNodes(child, listOfNodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```