# Access The All oneToMany under the Parent Object in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Hello I need to access all my OneToMany relation That created By Super user!
In other explanations I Have class named user that contain the List of User named by childes and when created a new user I getChildes and updated with new user , so In selection one user in jpa lazy mode (login with new user I created) everything fine , but if I created new user from user I created no problem but when login to main user I wana see the all users if write in math :

if A create user named B, A is master of B and B is child for A.

if B create new User Called C the B is master of C.

Now I need :

A master of B and C
so if I called list of childes from A listed :
B and C

but the Code I wrote Just show B as childe.

The classes :

```
package ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.internal;


import ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.external.EconomicCompany;
import ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.external.InvoiceEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
@Table(name = "table_users")
@Entity
public class User extends StorageInformation {
    @Column(name = "login_id", unique = true)
    String username;
    @Column
    String name, password, tel;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class)
    List<User> childs;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Scope scope = Scope.NONE;
    @Column
    String domain;

    @Column(name = "status_access")
    Integer status;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = EconomicCompany.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<EconomicCompany> economicCompanies;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Signature.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Signature> signatures;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = InvoiceEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<InvoiceEntity> invoiceEntities;
    @OneToOne
    Company company;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public List<User> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }

    public void setChilds(List<User> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public Scope getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(Scope scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<EconomicCompany> getEconomicCompanies() {
        return economicCompanies;
    }

    public void setEconomicCompanies(List<EconomicCompany> economicCompanies) {
        this.economicCompanies = economicCompanies;
    }

    public List<Signature> getSignatures() {
        return signatures;
    }

    public void setSignatures(List<Signature> signatures) {
        this.signatures = signatures;
    }

    public List<InvoiceEntity> getInvoiceEntities() {
        return invoiceEntities;
    }

    public void setInvoiceEntities(List<InvoiceEntity> invoiceEntities) {
        this.invoiceEntities = invoiceEntities;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

And Code snippet of User Maker :

```
 public void save() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean res = false;
        if (getUsername() != null) {
            try {
                Application.logger.info("User Domain : " + this.getScope() + " For : " + this.getUsername());
                User masterUser = service.loginUser(facesContext);
                MasterRepository repo = new MasterRepository();
                User childUser = new User();
                childUser.setStatus(getStatus());
                childUser.setScope(getScope());
                childUser.setTel(getTel());
                childUser.setPassword(getPassword());
                childUser.setDomain(getDomain());
                childUser.setName(getName());
                childUser.setUsername(getUsername());
                masterUser.getChilds().add(childUser);
                if (getId() > 0) {
                    childUser.setId(getId());
                }
                res = repo.save(masterUser);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Application.logger.fatal(e.getMessage());
            }
```

The Repository :

```
package ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.repo.implemented;

import ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.Application;
import ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.internal.User;
import ir.mehritco.megnatis.tax.repo.HibernateConnection;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;

import java.util.List;

public class MasterRepository {
    private HibernateConnection hibernateService = HibernateConnection.getInstance();

    public boolean save(User user) {
        user.setUsername(user.getUsername().toLowerCase());
        EntityManager entityManager = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        boolean executeSuccess = false;
        try {
            User entityUser = null;
            if (user.getId() <= 0) {
                Application.logger.info("load user with username : " + user.getUsername());
                User fromLoadRepo = findByUsername(user.getUsername());
                if (fromLoadRepo != null) {
                    entityUser = entityManager.find(User.class, findByUsername(user.getUsername()).getId());
                }
            } else {
                Application.logger.info("load user with id : " + user.getId());
                entityUser = entityManager.find(User.class, user.getId());
            }
            if (entityUser == null) {
                Application.logger.info("We are nothing find to update so we save user with id : " + user.getId());
                entityManager.persist((User) user);
            } else {
                user.setId(entityUser.getId());
                if (user.getPassword().equals("*************")) {
                    user.setPassword(entityUser.getPassword());
                }
                Application.logger.info("We find user and now going for update : " + user.getId());
                entityManager.merge((User) user);
            }
            executeSuccess = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            executeSuccess = false;
            Application.logger.fatal("save the user/update throw an Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (executeSuccess) {
                try {
                    transaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    executeSuccess = false;
                    Application.logger.fatal("Commit changes for save the user/update throw an Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return executeSuccess;
    }


    public User findById(long id) {
        if (id > 0) {
            EntityManager entityManager = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        username = username.toLowerCase();
        List<User> user;
        EntityManager entityManager = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
        CriteriaQuery<User> all = criteriaQuery.select(root);
        all.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("username"), username));
        TypedQuery<User> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);
        user = allQuery.getResultList();
        return (user == null || user.size() == 0) ? null : user.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I found missunderstood!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952460/return-list-of-nodes-a-tree-in-java-parent-can-have-multiple-child-nodes solve my problem!